# Report FLOPs with Intel Advisor XE

Tags: linux, flops, intel-parallel-studio, intel-advisor, roofline

I am usign the Intel Advisor 2018 (build 523188) on Linux CentOS 7.4 to profile a collection of benchmarks (I want to plot them all in a single Roofline plot) and I am using the command line tool advixe-cl to collect the survey, tripcounts and flops information for each benchmark.

However, I cannot find a way to report the measured performance in FLOPs (for each loop or function or even whole program) using the command line interface. The documentation I am looking at is found here https://software.intel.com/en-us/advisor-help-lin-command-line-interface-reference, but I think that it is not complete e.g. the options -flops-and-masks and -no-tip-counts are not mentioned anywhere.

Do you know if there is any way to report the measured flops via the command line interface? Or do you know where I can find a complete documentation of advixe-cl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first "collect" (means "profile") FLOPS data and, secondly, report it via user interface.

To **collect** the data: follow https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advisor-roofline (better and newer article) or https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-2017-user-guide-linux-running-roofline-analysis (older syntax).

To **report/investigate** the FLOP values/data it is recommended to launch Intel Advisor GUI: `$advixe-gui <project-dir>`

Alternatively you could report/explore FLOP values using *command line* reports (`$advixe-cl -report survey <project-dir>`).

See advixe-cl documentation at :
https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-2017-user-guide-linux-using-intel-advisor-command-line-interface  or https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-2017-user-guide-linux-report